# Question on English grammar structure

Tags: meaning-in-context, sentence-construction, difference, american-english

> 1. Apple Inc. is subject to tax charge according to the law of the state of California.
> 2. Apple Inc. is subject to the tax charge according to the law of the state of California.
> 3. Apple Inc. is subject to the law of the state of California for (the) income tax.
> 4. Apple Inc. is subject to pay (for) the income tax according to the law of the state of California.

Sorry to mind boggle with this, 
but as a person who has never acquired the native sense of grammar, 
I always get confused whenever I read sentences that are written on books that are written in English, over miscellaneous things like

> When to or when not to add Article (‘the’) and how the meaning of the sentence changes.

And I am left with further questions upon reading those 4 sentences.

What are some key differences between the sentence 1 and 2, and 3 and 4? And which sentence is more natural in modern American English?

No joke intended. I am just not very educated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first sentence,

> Apple Inc. is subject to tax charge according to the law of the state of California.

is correct and more natural in American English.

The second sentence,

> Apple Inc. is subject to the tax charge according to the law of the state of California.

is incorrect because of the word 'the' before the words 'tax charge'.

The third sentence,

> Apple Inc. is subject to the law of the state of California for (the) income tax.

is incorrect because of the word 'the' in brackets.

The fourth sentence,

> Apple Inc. is subject to pay (for) the income tax according to the law
>   of the state of California.

is incorrect because of the word 'for' in brackets and the word 'the' before the words 'income tax'.